# Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core

I threw my .NET Core application on a web server and unfortunately does not work, i.e. if I do not use the database, everything works, as I have a database in the project, unfortunately it is a white page. The following messages show in my logs:

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication.

The problem is that everything works without a problem locally. My connectionString looks like this:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=mssql6.webio.pl,2401;Database=reverse_tester;Uid=example;Password=example;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
  }
}
```

I added to connectionString IntegratedSecurity = false; but nothing gave it away

My website is white page: https://nieruchomosci.hostingasp.pl/

On localhost all works fine.

Comment: Change `Trusted_Connection=True` to `Trusted_Connection=False` in your connection string

Comment: @haim770 spent 3 hours looking for a solution before I wrote here, so that I would not go easy, but I did not find anything in the world that the solution could be so simple: D

Thank you, it works great :)